# how to set image to ImageView inside ListView in Xamarin?

Tags: listview, xamarin

I am now on a project by using xamarin.android. I have a listview on the screen and Imageview inside the listview, I used SimpleAdapter to display the data inside the collection. 
below is the function to extract data collection:

```
private JavaList<IDictionary<string, Object>> TriggerNetResAndFill()
    {

        string uri = "http://www.51yam.com/forum.php?mod=recommend";
        string content = string.Empty;
        var items = new JavaList<IDictionary<string, Object>>();
        var stream = streamPicker.GetUriStream(uri);
        content = streamPicker.GetStreamText(stream);

        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(content);

        HtmlNodeCollection keyNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='xst']");
        foreach (HtmlNode keyNode in keyNodes)
        {
            var map = new JavaDictionary<string, Object>();
            map.Add(KEY_ICON, userInfoPicker.GetU());
            items.Add(map);
        }  

        return items;
    }
```

the userInfoPicker.GetU() function is the function trying to get jpeg resource from a give url and return stream back:

```
 public Bitmap GetU()
    {

      var stream =   streamPicker.GetUriStream(iconU);
      Bitmap usericon = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
      return usericon;
    }
```

Then in mainactivity, I doing below stuff:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        listview = (ListView)FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listContent);

        processDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "loading", "pls wait...", true);

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            RunOnUiThread(new Action(() =>
            {
                listResult = TriggerNetResAndFill();

                var adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listResult, Resource.Drawable.list_content,
                new String[] { KEY_ICON, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC },
                new int[] { Resource.Id.lvw_custom_img, Resource.Id.lvw_custom_name, Resource.Id.lvw_custom_description });
                listview.Adapter = adapter;

                processDialog.Dismiss();

            }));
        })).Start();
    }
```

But the result is , I didn't get the image as expected. would any one give me advice on this? I am new to xamarin and android, I am just a C#er. expect your advice. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you implemented your `ViewHolder`, but usually you just have to set a  `ViewHolder` with your `ListView` and inside `InitializeView` from your `ViewHolder` you can do something like

```
image = rootView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.listViewImage);
image.SetImageBitmap(yourMap[desiredKey]);
```

If you want for any reason to clear the ImageView, you can do :

```
image.SetImageBitmap(null);
```

But if the bitmap is never set, that might explain why it doesn't load.